# Angular detect if a popup window is opened

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript1.4

In my board (written in Angular 4), the dialogues are opened like below:

***Importing ActivatedRoute, Router***

`import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';`

***Adding Router and ActivatedRoute references in constructor***

`constructor (
...
private _router: Router,
private _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
...)`

***And Using it in below way***

`this._router.navigate(['./', { outlets: { somemodal: 'somemodal', dialogs: null }, relativeTo: this._activatedRoute }]);`

**Requirement is** when you hit escape <kbd>Esc</kbd> it should show the removal modal (an other modal already implemented and working).

***But QA has raised an issue*** like when other popups (like scanned check image/ rescan  popup / customer id popup / error message popups) are present then on hit  <kbd>Esc</kbd> those popups should close first.

If no other popup are present, then only Removal modal will open, which is not happening at present. On hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> it is still opening the removal popup.

**Question:** How can I detect if other popups are present.

**Note** : At the very beginning of development, in some shared service, we could have created flag like `isPopupOpened: boolean = true` and on closing the same popup it should be turned to `isPopupOpened = false`. But this is not implemented and several modals are implemented, which all are opened in different stages in my board. An user may hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> at nay point of time. So I want to what is the solution of the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.

```
keyCommandHandler(command: Command): void {
        switch (command.name) {
          case 'App.Escape':
          if (this._router.url.indexOf('dialogs') === -1  && this._router.url.indexOf('subdialogs') === -1) {
            this.cancelHelper();
          }else {
            this._router.navigate(['./', { outlets: { dialogs: null }, relativeTo: this._activatedRoute }]);
          }
            break;
        }
      }
```

Just check if any dialogs or subdialogs is present in your URL. It works for me.

Comment: could you show more of your solution? for example the command class and the rest. appreciate your help thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You might need to maintain a state for each popup in shared service. Based on the state value you need to handle the popup display/close and user press ESC button. To handle keyboard events, you can use directive and shared service can be injected in Constructor to update the state.

Comment: problem is there are multiple modal popup may open and for none of the modal popup, while opening, such flag in shared service is created. I need such a thing in `ngOnInit()` i.e. `this._activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: any) => {
        if (params["modal"] === 'true') {
            this.isModalOpen = true;
        }else {
          this.isModalOpen = false;
        }` <= this does not work though :)