# Angular 8: Detect when download pop up window is active

Tags: angular, popup

I'm working on a bouncing arrow that encourages the user to click and download the file. So the user first clicks a "Download" button, which triggers the download at the bottom of the window. In angular, is there a way to detect this download pop up when it appears? Like detecting the router or something.

There was an answer here but the guy wasn't so specific
[Angular detect if a popup window is opened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52557355/angular-detect-if-a-popup-window-is-opened)

**arrow.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="showArrow">
  <div class="arrow">
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
  <p class="download-text">
    <i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>Double click the
    .exe file to run this program
  </p>
</div>
```

**arrow.component.ts**

```
  downloadClient() {
    window.location.href = environment.clientUrl;
    this.showArrow = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.showArrow = false;
    }, 8000);
  }
```

Currently it looks like this, user clicks on this download button:

[image]

User is prompted to download file (the bouncing arrow is at the bottom left of the screen, usually the file popup dialog doesn't appear on windows but it appears in mac OS, ignore it for now)

[image]

Instead of set time out is there a way to accurately show the arrow ONLY when the pop up is present? And that it works across different browsers (chrome/internet explorer) and even further, are we able to check that the downloaded file pinpoints to the correct one?

Appreciate your help!

Comment: my guess is you don't want to show this when popup is open, you want to show this arrow when the file starts downloading, right?

Comment: hey aakash! I've added a red arrow to make it clearer - I want the blue bouncing arrow to show as long as that bottom download bar (idk what's it called) showing the file is there. if the user somehow closes it I don't want the arrow to show.

Comment: no you can't detect that, your arrow will be visible even if that bar is closed. what you can do is show arrow for shorter period of time then remove it.